# How can I do a validation check with node.js and json?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I just started with web development and I know they are similar questions, but unfortunately I could not find a solution...

In my html file I have an Input field, where User should enter its Id. I want to check via a json file (where the IDs are stored), weather the ID has been entered correct or not.
For me it's not clear, how I can do this validation check by node js. Any suggestions?

test.html

```
<form class="test">
<label class="ID-Field">
    <input id="value" type="text" required/>
    <span class="placeholder">Your ID</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

data.json

```
{
    "inforamtion":[
 
    {  
     "ID": "123",
    "Name": "Vincent"
 },

 {
    "ID": "452",
    "Name": "Jean"

 },

 {
    "ID": "678",
    "Name": "Sopfie"
 }

]
}
```

index.js

```
    const http =require('http');
    const express = require('express');
    const { urlencoded } = require('body-parser');
    const { fstat } = require('fs');
    const { response } = require('express');
    
    const app = express();
    
    
    app.get('/test.html',function (req,res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +'/test.html'));
      })
      
    
    app.listen(4000, console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:4000`));


//Check ID

app.post('/database.json', (req, res) => {
    const result = information.find(({id}) => id === 'defined');
    console.log(result)

})
```

Comment: Are you using vanilla JS? Have you fetched the JSON objects from the backend?

Comment: thank you for your answer @khenriksson!   vanilla JS? - mhh just normal js.... no, I haven't fetched it yes, because am confused how to do it..I read something about it, but I don't know how to apply it to my case

Comment: Could you show us your node routes as well?

Comment: I have updated it. But it's just the beginning, what I have. Honestly, I don't really understand, how I connect it now in the index.js file, so that it works in the end...

Answer (score 1):

You can create new endpoint in your node app like.

```
app.post('/check', (req, res) => {})
```

After filling in your form you can perform ajax request to this endpoint where you send ID provided by user. In that endpoint you can get your json file, and try to find if you have any object with ID privded by user.

But first you need to change your data json to array to be able to use .find function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
[
    { id: 1, name: "Some name"},
    { id: 2, name: "Another name"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you @Damian. I updated the code (data.json & index.js) in my question. It's not working yet. So my question for my understanding is, can I just write `const result = information.find(({id}) => id === 'defined');` ?  Or is ` ...id === 'defined');` wrong? How can I do it, that all Id's in the json file will be checked ? And how can I put an display message, weather the ID is correct (in the json file) or not ? Would be great, if you could give me some hints.